# Error desconocido al compilar aplicación en dispositivo Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, depuración, compilar

Presento el siguiente error al tratar de compilar aplicación en un dispositivo en especifico: Ulefone Armor X5 con Android 10.0, el error sólo ocurre con esa aplicación debido a que he compilado perfectamente otras aplicaciones en ese dispositivo:

[image: Run APP Ulefone X5]

Revisé mi código y compilé la misma app en una Moto G6 con android 9.0 y en un Moto G8 Power con android 10.0 corre perfecto:

[image: Run APP Moto G8]

por lo que pude descartar que se trataba de la versión de android, busqué en internet pero no encontrar mucha información del problema, dejo el código de lo que estoy tratando de compilar.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static ArrayList<Contacto> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private static LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
private static  AdaptadorContacto adaptadorContacto;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listaContactos);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    adaptadorContacto = new AdaptadorContacto(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptadorContacto);

    readContactos(this);


}

public static boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

public static void sincronizarContactos(Context context){
    if(checkNetworkConnection(context)){
        final Database database = new Database(context);
        final SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.88.11/pruebas/getContactos.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        database.saveContactos(object.getInt("id"),
                                object.getString("nombre"),
                                object.getString("apellidos"),
                                object.getString("telefono"),
                                db);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
    }
}

public static void readContactos(Context context){
    arrayList.clear();
    Database database = new Database(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = database.readContactos(db);

    while (c.moveToNext()){

        Contacto contacto = new Contacto(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Contactos.NOMBRE)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Contactos.APELLIDOS)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Contactos.TELEFONO)));

        System.out.println("IMPRIMIENDO LOCAL: " + contacto.getNombre());
        arrayList.add(contacto);

    }

    adaptadorContacto.notifyDataSetChanged();
    c.close();
    database.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id == R.id.sincronizar){
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("sincronizando...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        new Sincronizar(this, progressDialog).execute();

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class Sincronizar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public Sincronizar(Context context, ProgressDialog progressDialog){
        this.context = context;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        sincronizarContactos(context);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.hide();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sincronizado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        readContactos(context);
     }
  }
}
```

Adaptador

```
public class AdaptadorContacto extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorContacto.MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Contacto> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public AdaptadorContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> arrayList){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdaptadorContacto.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_contacto, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorContacto.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.nombre.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNombre()+ " " + arrayList.get(position).getApellidos());
holder.telefono.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTelefono());
holder.avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView nombre, telefono;
    ImageView avatar;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNombre);
        telefono = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTelefono);
        avatar = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenContacto);
      }
   }
}
```

Clase MySingleton

```
public class MySingleton {
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private RequestQueue referenceQueue;
private static Context mCtx;

private MySingleton(Context context){
    mCtx = context;
    referenceQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

private RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
    if(referenceQueue==null){
        referenceQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return referenceQueue;
}
public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance==null){
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return  mInstance;
}
public<T> void addToRequestQue(Request<T> request){
    getRequestQueue().add(request);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionar creando el proyecto como un Empty Activity y pasando todas las clases del proyecto para el nuevo proyeto creado, al parecer algo en el Fragmen del primer proyecto estaba generando el problema, quizás presenta conflictos con ciertos parámetros del equipo